# Java API: Cross-site JSESSIONID is not maintained between requests

Tags: java, tomcat, cookies, jersey

I'm developing against a java/jersey API, and I think our CORS config is incorrect.

If I make a call to our login service, I get a `Set-Cookie` header back with the `JSESSIONID` set.  When I attempt a subsequent call to a service which requires a cookie, the `JSESSIONID` isn't being sent.

Here's the response header from the login request:
[image: Login Headers]

I use the following code to make the followup request:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', 'some/url', true)
xhr.withCredentials = true
xhr.send(null)
```

Which fails, returning the following headers:
[image: Followup Headers]

It looks like the Tomcat filter is properly configured, but clearly something is off.  If it's relevant, I'm doing this over a VPN.

Comment: Cookies doesn't work with adress ip origin, try to change your access-allow-control-origin to something like "adress.project.com" and change your host file to link "adress.project.com" to your origin ip "192.168.1.85"

Comment: I believe the CORS filter is set to `origin` as opposed to something specific already.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I needed to send the initial `login` call with credentials as well.

Comment: I didn't understand how you fix this issue ?